# PostgreSQL and Entity Framework Core 3.1 generating a query that contains an inline query / sub query

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I have a .NET Core / EF Core 3.1 application over a PostgreSQL database. I am looking up customers. At the moment, I am making two trips to the database. The first trip, is to find me all the customer Ids that match my search term, the second query then retrieves all the related entities for that customer and brings them back in one go. For example:

Get customer Ids by name and post code:

```
customerIds = (from c in loyalty.Customer.AsNoTracking()
                            where c.FirstName.ToLower() == request.CustomerSearchParameters.FirstName.ToLower() &&
                                  c.LastName.ToLower() == request.CustomerSearchParameters.LastName.ToLower()
                            join a in loyalty.Address on c.CustomerInternalId equals a.CustomerInternalId
                            where a.Postcode == request.CustomerSearchParameters.PostCode
                            select c.CustomerInternalId).ToList();
```

Then get all the entities for those customer Id(s).

```
            var customers = (from c in loyalty.Customer.AsNoTracking()
                             where customerIds.Contains(c.CustomerInternalId)
                    select c)
                .Include(c => c.ContactInformation).AsNoTracking()
                .Include(c => c.Address).AsNoTracking()
                .Include(c => c.MarketingPreferences).AsNoTracking()
                .Include(c => c.ContentTypePreferences).AsNoTracking()
                .Include(c => c.ExternalCards).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

This obviously generates two queries:

First:

```
SELECT c.customer_internal_id

FROM customer AS c

INNER JOIN address AS a ON c.customer_internal_id = a.customer_internal_id

WHERE ((LOWER(c.first_name) = @__ToLower_0) AND (LOWER(c.last_name) = @__ToLower_1)) AND (a.postcode = @__request_CustomerSearchParameters_PostCode_2)
```

Then

```
SELECT c.customer_internal_id, c.business_partner_id, c.created_date, c.customer_type, c.date_of_birth, c.first_name, c.gender, c.home_store_id, c.home_store_updated, c.last_name, c.loyalty_db_id, c.mca_id, c.status, c.status_reason, c.store_joined, c.title, c.updated_by, c.updated_date, c.updating_store, c0.contact_internal_id, c0.contact_type, c0.contact_value, c0.created_date, c0.customer_internal_id, c0.updated_by, c0.updated_date, c0.updating_store, c0.validated, a.address_internal_id, a.address_line_1, a.address_line_2, a.address_type, a.address_undeliverable, a.address_validated, a.country, a.created_date, a.customer_internal_id, a.postcode, a.region, a.suburb, a.updated_by, a.updated_date, a.updating_store, m.customer_internal_id, m.channel_id, m.created_date, m.opt_in, m.updated_by, m.updated_date, m.updating_store, m.valid_from_date, c1.customer_internal_id, c1.channel_id, c1.type_id, c1.created_date, c1.opt_in, c1.updated_by, c1.updated_date, c1.updating_store, c1.valid_from_date, e.customer_internal_id, e.card_number, e.card_design, e.card_status, e.card_type, e.created_date, e.updated_by, e.updated_date, e.updating_store

FROM customer AS c

LEFT JOIN contact_information AS c0 ON c.customer_internal_id = c0.customer_internal_id

LEFT JOIN address AS a ON c.customer_internal_id = a.customer_internal_id

LEFT JOIN marketing_preferences AS m ON c.customer_internal_id = m.customer_internal_id

LEFT JOIN content_type_preferences AS c1 ON c.customer_internal_id = c1.customer_internal_id

LEFT JOIN external_cards AS e ON c.customer_internal_id = e.customer_internal_id

WHERE c.customer_internal_id IN ('7495c17d-3e53-4808-a991-6c185c4ced7b')

ORDER BY c.customer_internal_id, c0.contact_internal_id, c0.contact_type, a.address_internal_id, m.customer_internal_id, m.channel_id, c1.customer_internal_id, c1.channel_id, c1.type_id, e.customer_internal_id, e.card_number
```

Is there any way through EF Core, that I can use a sub query to effectively make only one trip to the database? E.g.

```
SELECT attribute, 
attribute, 
attribute, 
attribute, 
attribute
FROM TABLE 
LEFT JOIN OTHER TABLE
LEFT JOIN OTHER TABLE
WHERE customer_internal_id IN (
SELECT customer_internal_id from Customer 
WHERE first name = x AND last name = X AND post code = x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var customers = (from customer in loyalty.Customer
                    .Include(c => c.ContactInformation)
                    .Include(c => c.Address)
                    .Include(c => c.MarketingPreferences)
                    .Include(c => c.ContentTypePreferences)
                    .Include(c => c.ExternalCards)
                    .AsNoTracking() 
                from address in loyalty.Address.Where(a => a.CustomerInternalId == customer.CustomerInternalId)
                where customer.FirstName.ToLower() == request.CustomerSearchParameters.FirstName.ToLower() 
                  && customer.LastName.ToLower() == request.CustomerSearchParameters.LastName.ToLower()
                  && address.Address.Postcode == request.CustomerSearchParameters.PostCode
                select customer).ToList();
```

Comment: This doesn't compile. ICollection<Address> does not contain a definition for Postcode. Customer to Address is a one-to-many relationship, so I don't think your code knows which Addresses post code to match on. I think my SQL pseudo query wasn't written well. The sub query should be WHERE customer_internal_id IN (
SELECT customer_internal_id from Customer 
WHERE first name = x AND last name = X AND post code IN (select post code from Address where customer_internal_id = Customer.customer_internal_id)